# How can I later get access to something created in a let

Tags: clojure

For example

```clj
(def inc-map (let [inum (atom 0)]
               {:countup (fn[](swap! inum inc))
                :get     (fn[](@inum))}))

((inc-map :countup )) ;increase inside value
; ⇒ 1

((inc-map :get)) ;get current value
; ⇒ 1
```

Can I get access `inum` when I want to add more functions later?

E.g. I want to do this:

```
(def inc-map 
  (assoc inc-map :countdown (fn[] ???)))
```

How can I access `inum` at `???`?

Comment: My guess is: you can't easily do it. You could hold on to the atom in the map too.

Comment: Just illustrating what @cfrick said:  `{:state inum ... `

Comment: thanks. It helps.
I want to change seesaw function. 
but I think make one

Answer (score 2):

it could be possible, if you expose one more function, say `:update`, enclosing the `inum` value.

```
(def inc-map (let [inum (atom 0)]
               {:update (fn [f & args] (apply swap! inum f args))
                :countup (fn [] (swap! inum inc))
                :get (fn [] @inum)}))

user> (def inc-dec-map (assoc inc-map :countdown
                              (fn [] ((inc-map :update) dec))))
#'user/inc-dec-map
user> ((inc-dec-map :countup))
;;=> 1

user> ((inc-dec-map :countup))
;;=> 2

user> ((inc-dec-map :countdown))
;;=> 1

user> ((inc-dec-map :countdown))
;;=> 0

user> ((inc-dec-map :countdown))
;;=> -1
```

and then you can just seal it, dissoc'ing `:update`, (say if you make it publicly accessed to some other namespace.

otherwise you could provide an getter/updater to the ops object:

```
(def counter-ops (let [inum (atom 0)
                       ops (atom {:countup (fn [] (swap! inum inc))
                                  :get     (fn [] @inum)})]
                   (fn
                     ;; get operations map snapshot
                     ([] @ops)
                     ;; get operation
                     ([op] (-> ops deref op))
                     ;; set operation
                     ([op f & args] (swap! ops assoc op (fn [& args] (apply f inum args)))))))

user> (counter-ops :countdown (fn [inum] (swap! inum dec)))

user> (counter-ops :decrease-by (fn [inum n] (swap! inum - n)))

user> ((counter-ops :countdown))
;;=> -1

user> ((counter-ops :countdown))
;;=> -2

user> ((counter-ops :countup))
;;=> -1

user> ((counter-ops :countup))
;;=> 0

user> ((counter-ops :decrease-by) 10)
;;=> -10
```

seal it to be locked for any subsequent op additions:

```
user> (def counter-ops-sealed (counter-ops))
#'user/counter-ops-sealed

user> ((counter-ops-sealed :countup))
;;=> 2

user> ((counter-ops-sealed :countdown))
;;=> 1
```

Comment: sorry. I don't want change original source.
 I want change function what made by proxy.
so i made a question for hint for that. 
but thanks. maybe there is no solutions.
except making another function